# Mutation Observer causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I'm trying to modify the images of a website that uses react and takes the images via API and generates a gallery with Mutation Observer but has caused an infinity loop error. The result I have with this code is this:

**RESULT**

```
herehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
hereherehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
herehereherehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
hereherehereherehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
herehereherehereherehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
hereherehereherehereherehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
herehereherehereherehereherehttp://www.image.com/image.jpg
```

**CODE**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

const muta = document.querySelector("#root");
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

           mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {

                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function (node) {

                    if (typeof node.getElementsByTagName !== 'function') {
                        return;
                  }

                  let section = document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];
                  let images = section.getElementsByTagName('img');

                  Array.from(images).forEach(function(image){
                    let newimg =  'here'+image.src;
                    if(image.src !== newimg){

                      image.src = newimg;
                    }

                  });


            });

         });       

});

var observerConfig = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
}
observer.observe(muta, observerConfig);
});
```

Comment: It's working like this as per the specification. You need to skip modification of the src if it already starts with the string you're adding.

Comment: the "here" was just an example the change I want is more complex. There is no way I can check with startsWith. Is there any way for the observer mutation to observe only once?

Comment: Not really. You can disconnect() the observer and even do takeRecords() but it'll only work for the next event loop tick. You'll **have** to find a way to avoid re-processing the same element. Like maybe use a `WeakSet` of the elements or add an *expando* property directly to the element so you can check it.